# Angular component: change css variable for application but not component itself

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-reactive-forms, css-variables

I have an application that uses css variables for most styling, such as font-size.

```
:root {
  --font_size_base: 16px;
}
body {
  font-size: var(--font_size_base);
}
```

I need to create a component that change change that root variable and increase font size but I need the font size **inside that component** to remain constant.

In the component I have an HTML input type range:

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if (value.fontSize) {
        this.document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
          '--font_size_base',
          `${value.fontSize}px`
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

This does change the font size, but it of course also affects the fonts inside the component.  I need to define a font size inside the component and have it not be affected. I can prevent this with CSS changes by setting view encapsulation to shadowdom, but this is not CSS but a style tag on the body tag directly, so it still affect my component.

I tried assigning a value inside the component's CSS but it did not work

```
:host {
  --font_size_base: 12;
}
```

Is this even possible?  Here's a stackblitz of the situation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hghqm3?file=src/app/controller/controller.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly set a font size for you component, like that:

```
:host {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

or

```
:host {
  --font_size_base: 12px;
  font-size: var(--font_size_base);
}
```

Comment: Can i re-define variables in the host?

Comment: @Steve yes, but you need to redefine font-size also. I have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use in styles.css

```
app-controller
{
  --font_size_base: 12px;
}
```

See that app-controler is the "selector" of your component

And in your controller.css

```
.child{
  font-size:var(--font_size_base)
}
```